# Alternative to Explode which handles integers - str_split() cannot be used

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, explode

I am trying to take a value from a database, save that value as an array and then explode the array with a delimiter of :, placing the first value into another column in the same table, leaving the rest of the values where they came from. I think the code I have should do the trick but the value I want to explode contains integers which explode apparently does not handle well(?). I also cannot use str_split() as we have recently upgraded to PHP 7.2 and str_split() is deprecated. I've spent a lot of time on Google researching alternatives but I don't really see how any of them can help me.

This is my latest attempt, using str_word_count():

```
$queryGetStrings = 'SELECT roleText FROM table1.tempRoles';
$resultGetStrings = mysqli_query($conn,$queryGetStrings) or die("<br> <br>".$queryGetStrings."<br><br>".mysqli_error($conn));
$resultsArray = mysqli_fetch_all($resultGetStrings);

$explode_row = str_word_count($resultsArray, 1, '_123456789');

foreach($resultsArray as $key => $row) {
//Line below is from my explode attempt
     //$explode_row = explode(":", $row);

     $addSplitColumns = "UPDATE table1.tempRoles SET `user` = '" . $explode_row[0] . "'";
     $executeSplitColumns = mysqli_query($conn, $addSplitColumns) or die("<br><br>" . 

$addSplitColumns . "<br><br>" . mysqli_error($conn));
```

Could anyone recommend an alternative method to doing this? I'm relatively new to back-end programming so my repository is bleak at best. I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried explode with integers - not sure where you got the idea of there being a problem.

Comment: "_contains integers which explode apparently does not handle well(?)_" Apparently? Where did you read that?

Comment: One of the errors I was getting with this code was regarding integers which led me to believe that perhaps explode isn't the right way to go. Judging by your responses, I assume I am wrong

Comment: What do the data values actually look like?

Comment: the Warning rather, not error is as follows: 'Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string', and it refers to $explode_row = explode(":", $row); which I have now uncommented. I have also commented out the str_word_count line

Comment: I can't give a direct example of the data for security purposes but an example would be nsmith:a_b_j_t:duo:PADH:RI1r02

Answer (score 0):

All you should do is to cast the second argument of explode to string:

```
$explode_row = explode(":", (string) $row);
```

If it makes sense only: before updating the row you should verify the length of the resulted array. If you have only a single value inside the array, it means that the string has no `:`

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. Though, the length of the array could be any length but will always be greater than 1.